# Error with Paperclip Photo uploads (S3) on Mobile in Dokku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, digital-ocean, dokku

**UPDATE**

I created a very simple app using paperclip having a Person model and avatar attachment.  I then deployed it to a fresh new Dokku droplet and encountered the same issue as with my main App.  I then read about ActiveStorage and thought maybe I'd see some success with that, so I converted the simple app to use ActiveStorage rather than Paperclip, but I still have the same issue on mobile uploads caught from the device camera.

This seems like an issue with Dokku from what I've seen (especially since the functionality works on Heroku), but I really don't know where to go from here.  I don't have any special code for handling mobile uploads. I'm using simple_form for the form controls, and standard image_tag syntax for displaying.  I'm also using Devise for user accounts (which I added to my simple app as well just to replicate).  The thing is that my logs show nothing when I get the Dokku error message, it's like the request never makes it off of my phone.

Still looking for help on this, thanks!

---

I have an app that has paperclip uploads enabled for optional photos and PDFs attachments on my model.  Everything works perfectly except in my production server when trying to attach files on Mobile (iOS).

I am using Dokku (via DigitalOcean) for Production, and Heroku for Test.  I am using Amazon S3 for storage of file uploads.

**Works:**

- Development: Uploads work from PC (no way of testing on mobile here)
- Test (Heroku): Uploads work from both PC and Mobile
- Production (Dokku/DO): All Uploads work from PC. PDF uploads work from mobile. Photo uploads work from mobile if choosing a photo existing already in the phone.

**Doesn't Work:**

- Production (Dokku/DO): Photo uploads from mobile (using the built in iOS/Safari Take photo functionality) go to an error page on Dokku. The error page says "The page you were looking for cannot be served."

When I check the application logs from Dokku, I didn't see any errors.  I enabled the live-mode logs (dokku logs application -t) to monitor while I tried an upload from mobile, and once I clicked the submit button, nothing was reported to the logs, it simply went to the error page on my device.

I am thinking it's an issue with my Dokku/deployment configuration, since it works fine in Heroku.  I may be missing something on the Dokku side. I don't have HTTPS enabled on Heroku since I'm using the free tier, but I do have HTTPS enabled on Dokku via LetsEncrypt. I'm not sure if this could be the reason for the error or not.

Anyway, here is some relevant code from my app. Any ideas much appreciated!

**Model.rb**

```
    has_attached_file :attachment,
        styles: { large: ["1000x1000>", :png], medium: ["300x300>", :png], thumb: ["100x100>", :png] }

    validates_attachment_content_type :attachment,
        content_type: [
          "image/jpg", 
          "image/jpeg", 
          "image/png", 
          "image/gif",
          "application/pdf",

          "file/txt",
          "text/plain",

          "application/doc",
          "application/msword", 

          "application/vnd.ms-excel",     
          "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
          ],
        message: "Sorry! We do not accept the attached file type"
```

**model_controller.rb**

```
    def transaction_params
        params.require(:transaction).permit(:trx_date, :description, :amount, :trx_type, :memo, :attachment, :attachment_file_name)
    end
```

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
  # Paperclip settings
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: {
      bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
      access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
      s3_region: ENV['S3_REGION'],
      s3_host_name: ENV['S3_HOST_NAME']
    }
  }
```

**Output of "dokku config myapp"**

```
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:    **masked**
S3_BUCKET_NAME:           mybucketname
DOKKU_APP_RESTORE:        1
DOKKU_NGINX_SSL_PORT:     443
S3_REGION:                us-east-2
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:        **masked**
DOKKU_APP_TYPE:           herokuish
DOKKU_NGINX_PORT:         80
DOKKU_PROXY_PORT_MAP:     http:80:5000 https:443:5000
DATABASE_URL:             **masked**
DOKKU_LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL:  **masked**
S3_HOST_NAME:             s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: You said you use S3 as your storage. Does the image appear on S3 when you upload it in production via mobile app?

Comment: No it does not make it that far.  It's almost as if nothing happens on the server side when I click "Submit".

Comment: Since your computer site works in production and mobile site on test / heroku, it must be a conflict between dokker and ios / paperclip. Could you write some custom code and see if you can send any data via ios trough production? I think the issue might be somewhere in your ios code. I suggest you to write a super simple app for dokker with paperclip and try to write a simple function for the ios part to upload something. This might help to pin down the issue / bug.

Comment: @Prometheus please see the updates in my original question. Thanks!

Comment: Since its a dokker thing, try to (if you haven't already) contact the support, create a ticket on the github paperclip gem and report it there. This is a more 'special' issue. Would you like to use heroku instead for production? There are also some other alternatives. I know this isnt a fix of your problem, but it might be the only real 'alternative' right now. Hope you can fix it asap!

Comment: @Prometheus I have resolved the issue (see answer).  Thanks for your help, your suggestions helped lead me to find the solution :)

Comment: Awesome! You did a great job finding the problem!

Answer (score 4):

I determined the cause of the error by installing Postman and using the Proxy server to view more details about the client requests from my phone.  I discovered the server was returning an error 413 Request Entity Too Large.

After some searching, I found that I needed to update my nginx configuration by adding the file in my app directory

```
/home/dokku/<myapp>/nginx.conf.d/upload.conf
```

In that file I inserted the line:

```
client_max_body_size 50M;
```

Afterwards I restarted my dokku container and everything works fine now :)

Thanks for the help all